# Make the route parameter actually appear in the address bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a tiny application in MVC 3.
In this tiny application, I want my URLs very clear and consistent.

There's just one controller with one action with one parameter.
If no value is provided (that is, `/` is requested by the browser), then a form is displayed to collect that single value. If a value is provided, a page is rendered.

The only route is this one:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",
  "{account}",
  new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", account = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This all works fine, but the `account` parameter never appears in the address line as a part of the URL. I can manually type `test.com/some_account` and it will work, but other than that, the `account` goes as a post parameter and therefore does not appear. And if I use `FormMethods.Get` in my form, I get `?account=whatever` appended to the URL, which is also not what I want and which goes against my understanding. My understanding was that the MVC framework would try to use parameters set in the route, and only if not found, it would append them after the `?`.

I've tried various flavours of setting the routes -- one route with a default parameter, or one route with a required parameter, or two routes (one with a required parameter and one without parameters); I've tried mixing `HttpGet`/`HttpPost` in all possible ways; I've tried using single action method with optional parameter `string account = null` and using two action methods (one with parameter, one without), but I simply can't get the thing appear in the URL.

I have also consulted the Steven Sanderson's book on MVC 3, but on the screenshots there are no parameters either (a details page for Kayak is displayed, but the URL in the address bar is `htpp://localhost:XXXX/`).

The only thing that definitely works and does what I want is

```cs
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { account = "whatever" });
```

But in order to do it, I have to first check the raw incoming URL and do not redirect if it already contains an `account` in it, otherwise it is an infinite loop. This seems way too strange and unnecessary.

What is the correct way to make `account` always appear as a part of the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding was that the MVC framework would try to use
>   parameters set in the route, and only if not found, it would append
>   them after the ?

Your understanding is not correct. ASP.NET MVC doesn't append anything. It's the client browser sending the form submission as defined in the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13):

> The method attribute of the FORM element specifies the HTTP method used
>   to send the form to the processing agent. This attribute may take two
>   values:
>
> - get: With the HTTP "get" method, the form data set is appended to the URI specified by the action attribute (with a question-mark ("?")
>     as separator) and this new URI is sent to the processing agent.
> - post: With the HTTP "post" method, the form data set is included in the body of the form and sent to the processing agent.

ASP.NET MVC routes are used to parse an incoming client HTTP request and redispatch it to the corresponding controller actions. They are also used by HTML helpers such as `Html.ActionLink` or `Html.BeginForm` to generate correct routes. It's just that for your specific scenario where you need to submit a user entered value as part of the url path (not query string) the HTML specification has nothing to offer you.

So, if you want to fight against the HTML specification you will have to use other tools: javascript. So you could use GET method and subscribe to the submit handler of the form and inside it manipulate the url so the value that was appended after the ? satisfy your requirements.

Don't think of this as ASP.NET MVC and routes and stuff. Think of it as a simple HTML page (which is what the browser sees of course) and start tackling the problem from that side. How would you in a simple HTML page achieve this?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. In my silly thoughs, MVC would do something like, "Analyse request - Find first matching route - Hey, one of parameters after the `?` has the same name as the missing optional parameter, so lets pretend it was there all the time." Thinking of it now, I realise that even if MVC actually did that, the browser wouldn't know and wouldn't update its address bar, unless presented with a redirect.